# What is the difference between 'service apache2 reload' and 'sudo systemctl restart apache2'?

Tags: linux, shell, service, systemctl

What is the difference between `service apache2 reload` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2`?

I understand that one uses sudo and others don't. 
Also, I can understand the difference between reloading and restart. 
But what is the major difference between these two commands?

Comment: Again, That question is about difference between "systemctl restart" and "systemctl start", whereas mine is about 'service apache2 reload' vs 'sudo systemctl restart apache2' ? People who don't know the answer, it is a completely different question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Restart = stop + start**

**Reload = remain running + re-read configuration files**

Comment: But in one command we use service and another command we use systemctl. Why is that so? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

We could define it like this:

> Restart--> STOP the service and then it will START the service.

Now comes Reload option.

> Reload--> Read .service file for which you have executed the command
>   and if any changes happened it will start using those changes now, so
>   each time a change happens in any service file a reload is needed. You
>   could even see this message coming, lets say you have changed a
>   service and you forgot to reload it so whenever you run any systemctl
>   command towards that service it will throw an error to reload it.